# I am looking for statistics on the percentage children's books versus other genres in self-publishing

Tags: self-publishing, book, children

I have tried doing searches for this and can't seem to track down the exact numbers. The sources will list the top selling genres but that doesn't include children's books.

Comment: Hello and welcome to our site!  A few questions... are you looking for total volume sold?  Are you looking to see what percentage of Fantasy books are children books? What particular stat are you interested in?

Comment: You might try asking this question on Open Data SE.

Comment: I would like to know what percentage of all self-published books are picture books and chapter books for children.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't specify which market you are interested in, I assume you want to know about Germany ;-)

In Germany, the book market is divided into the following merchandise groups:

[image]

The 15.8% market share of books for children and adolescents is in turn subdivided into the following merchandise groups:

[image]

Please note that "Learning" and "Non-Fiction" are both comprised of books for children as well as adolescents.

Also, there is no "Middle Grade" segment in Germany as there is in the US. Middle Grade books are subsumed under the children's and adolescent fiction categories.

There are no numbers for self-published books.

*(Statistic: Börsenverein des Deutschen Buchhandels; Chart: self-made)*

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: @Secespitus And why would I need to do that? Is there anything wrong with my answer?

Comment: Nope, just a tip because most newcomers don't realize there are these resources on SE sites. That's why I always refer people to those when I see that they are new and this was your first post as an unregistered user. SE can be quite weird at first and knowing where to look stuff up like "putting on hold" and "privileges" can be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I did not find any hard statistics in my searching. I assume someone tracks these sorts of statistics but may not make them readily available to the public.  You might want to contact the Society of Children's Book Writers and Illustrators ([SCBWI](https://www.scbwi.org/)) or [Publisher's weekly](https://www.publishersweekly.com/).

SCBWI offers resources on self-publishing for children's lit authors. I did not see the statistics you want in their publications but someone there might have that information or know where to get it, since they are dedicated to helping authors and illustrators get published.

I'm not as familiar with Publisher's weekly but it is an organization dedicated to all things publishing, including self-publishing. They are a likely source for the information as well.

Comment: I feel like this is verging on a link-only answer, and might get deleted.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Please note that the answer form should be used for full-fledged answers. You mention some interesting links that might help the author of the question, but just mentioning links is what we call a "link-only" answer and might get deleted. Can you [edit] your answer to explain for example why it's hard/not likely to find statistics on this matter and why these links might be helpful to the reader of this question? Currently this looks like a comment. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. We can be weird... Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

What I'm seeing around seems a few years old with a quick google search, but this [Statista](https://www.statista.com/search/?q=%20children%20books&sortMethod=idrelevance&isRegionPref=124&sortMethodMobile=idrelevance&statistics=1&accuracy=and&isoregion=0&isocountrySearch=&category=0&interval=0&archive=1&language=0) website may have a report to answer your question or something to get you started at least.

Hope this helps if you're still looking for an answer.